# SHORT way to map list into another

Tags: python, django

I have the following list and dict :

```
[u'customer_id', u'bank_statement', u'pay_stub']
```

and

```
REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('void_cheque',         _('Void Cheque')),
    ('pay_stub',            _('Pay Stub')),
    ('bank_statement',      _('Bank Statement (31 days)')),
    ('bank_statement_60',   _('Bank Statement (60 days)')),
    ('csst_statement',      _('CSST Statement')),
    ('saaq_statement',      _('SAAQ Statement')),
    ('cara_statement',      _('CARA Statement')),
    ('insurance_letter',    _('Insurance Letter')),
    ('t4',                  _('T4')),
    ('welfare_chart',       _('Welfare Chart')),
    ('raqp_chart',          _('RAQP Chart')),
    ('customer_id',         _('Customer ID')),
    ('proof_of_residence',  _('Proof Of Residence')),
    ('bankruptcy_proof',    _('Bankruptcy Proof')),
    ('consumer_proposal',   _('Consumer Proposal')),
    ('signed_contract',     _('Signed Contract')),
)
```

I already know I could access each element on that way

```
list = dict(Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES)
list['void_cheque']
```

The purpose of this question is to convert the first list into

```
['Void Cheque', 'Bank Statement (31 days)', 'Pay Stub']
```

How, with a short line, could I map the first list into that last list in using the dictionnary? I know I could do it with simple `for` statement, but I want to code it under a single line in such a way I could return it inside a function... `return your_code`

Comment: What is `Meta`? Is this `Django`? If so, add the tag. The 2nd list is not a list if enclosed with `( )`, but rather a `tuple` of `tuple`s. Are you asking how to get map the `dict` values to the 1st lists element strings?

Comment: Efficiency in terms of time complexity? Have you tried just mapping over the dictionary?

Comment: @pstatix I will not show you my `Meta` class, because it is irrelevant here. Yes, it is Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a 1-liner for initialization, but you can use a simple list comprehension to get it:

```
things = [u'customer_id', u'bank_statement', u'pay_stub']

types = dict(Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES) # dont use `list` as variable name

new_things = [types[thing] for thing in things if thing in types]
```

Comment: @J.Doe You need to step through your code and see what the `dict()` method returns on your classes data when called. The answer lies there. You asked for a mapping of list elements; both @ Daniel and I have supplied that for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`:

```
choices = [u'customer_id', u'bank_statement', u'pay_stub']
choices = list(map(dict(Meta.REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES).get, choices))
```

Comment: I got `[<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fcf6d4f29d0>,
 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fcf6d4f2550>,
 <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fcf6d4f2510>]`. How could I change `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fcf6d4f29d0>` into `Void cheque`?

Comment: Very clean. Comparable to list comprehension as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map). I'd say it is not as _pythontic_ though.

Comment: @J.Doe That is going to depend on how your `Meta` allows for its `REQUEST_DOCUMENT_TYPE_CHOICES` to be built into the `dict()` call. So not it appears that your class _is_ relevant. With a proper `dict` object, the code works.

Comment: I know that I could access `Void cheque` with `<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ at 0x7fcf6d4f29d0>.capitalized()`. Could you modify that answer so that it work with it and I will accept your answer.